# lezyne super gps wont record data on turbo trainer rides

Tags: bike-computer

I just purchased a lezyne super gps and have had no problems on out door rides but indoors where there is no gps signal it refuses to record the data from my power meter. Is there something basic I am doing wrong?

Comment: I haven't seen this bike computer in person, but it looks like some versions of it don't actually use wheel sensors so I'm not sure how they can tell if a bike is even being ridden indoors on rollers/trainers.

Comment: Many computers have a minimum distance travelled to start recording (which may be by gps or sensor). You may be able to set this to zero, and/or get a GPS fix at the window if the computer can move that far.

Comment: If your unit communicates with ANT+ sensors it might be possible to add a wheel sensor, like the magnetless from Garmin or any other where the sensor sits on the stay and gets impulses from a magnet on a spoke. Check the handbook and maybe borrow a sensor from a cycling mate. They are easy to switch between bikes.